# How can I get a list of all the files I have in my Google Drive using PHP?

Tags: google-drive-api

I want to list all the files from my Google drive using my "DriveFiles.php" file where I can display the files and its details.

I am a beginner so a complete code will be helpful.

Thanks.

My code:

```
<?php
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_DriveService.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/io/Google_HttpRequest.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_Oauth2Service.php';

// initialize a client with application credentials and required scopes.
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId('CLIENT_ID');
$client->setClientSecret('CLIENT_SECRET');
$client->setRedirectUri('REDIRECT_URI');
$client->setScopes(array(
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'));
$client->setUseObjects(true);


if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    session_start();
    print_r($_SESSION);
    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
    // initialize the drive service with the client.
    $services = new Google_DriveService($client);
    retrieveAllFiles($services);

}



if(!$client->getAccessToken()){
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    echo '<a class="login" href="'.$authUrl.'">Login</a>';
}


function retrieveAllFiles($service) {
    $result = array();
    $pageToken = NULL;

    do {
        try {
            $parameters = array();
            if ($pageToken) {
                $parameters['pageToken'] = $pageToken;
            }
            $files = $service->files->listFiles($parameters);

            $result = array_merge($result, $files->getItems());
            $pageToken = $files->getNextPageToken();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
            $pageToken = NULL;
        }
    } while ($pageToken);
    return $result;
}
?>
```

When i execute i get an error :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Exception' with message 'Cant add services after having authenticated' in D:\GT_local\Public\google-api-php-client\src\Google_Client.php:115 Stack trace: #0 D:\GT_local\Public\google-api-php-client\src\contrib\Google_DriveService.php(1258): Google_Client->addService('drive', 'v2') #1 D:\GT_local\Public\quickstart.php(55): Google_DriveService->__construct(Object(Google_Client)) #2 {main} thrown in "FILE_LOCATION(C://google-api-php-client\src\Google_Client.php on line 115)"
```

WHAT SHOULD I DO?

Answer (score 2):

[`files.list` docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list) contain a working sample with pagination:  You can use [DrEdit](https://github.com/googledrive/dredit) as a boilerplate project.